# android room always display closed in database inspector

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to use Database Inspector in Android Studio.

When I run the app on the device, inspector always showing my application database

[image]

Is there anything I need to set before using it?
I am not using db.closed()

And here is my database module code

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        //For singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase?= null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                .addCallback(
                    object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                        }
                    }
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue.  DB is always closed, is there a setting when building room to open it for debug apps?

Comment: @JPM I don't know why db is closed always. I'm sorry, but the problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: @JPM I don't know if this is a way to solve the problem, but to tell you one thing, when I call any table in the database (app settings in my case), the closed point disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some operation on DB e.g getlist
I have same issue when I am not in the page where DB is getting access.
Once I am in page, issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Check the integrity of your database. You deleted an attribute, renamed a field, or deleted a model that is being referenced or imported in some class, when the room tries to load its data there is an integrity error and therefore it appears as closed.

Check your build and debug logs. I had the same problem and I solved it by the error logs and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is because in your actual session the connection is close... in other words you must execute one qwery on your app and the connection will be open.

Other option is create your create an instance on your main activity, this instance will open your database connection every time.